# Implement Gitlab AutoDevops with ArgoCD

Tags: continuous-integration, continuous-deployment, gitlab-ci-runner, argocd, gitlab-autodevops

We have AutoDevops feature implemented with help of gitlab runner and managing the CD stage with ArgoCD. So the CI pipeline builds a docker image , pushes it to gitlab registry and CD stages use the pushed image to deploy the application with help of ArgoCD. On every commit, gitlab runner will trigger the pipeline. Is there are way in which we can use ArgoCD alone to handle this scenario so that the pipeline gets triggered automatically without having to configure runners?

Answer (score 0):

To avoid having both gitlab runner and argocd running in your cluster, you would configure a gitlab webhook pointing to an [ArgoCD Git Webhook Configuration](https://argoproj.github.io/argo-cd/operator-manual/webhook/).
Your ArgoCD application would then handle all the rest.